# Waterline lifecycle callback on FindOne?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, lifecycle, waterline, sails-postgresql

Waterline supports lifecycle callbacks ([docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks)). My `User` model has:

```
beforeValidate: hash_password,
beforeCreate: hash_password,
beforeUpdate: hash_password
```

Which works fine for creating/updating records (I double checked in the database).

However on my `findOne` I always get a `NotFoundError`:

```
User.findOne({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, (err, user) =>
                 cb(err ? err : !user ? new NotFoundError('User') : null)
```

Turning on database logging, I confirmed that the password in the `findOne` is never hashed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to explicitly hash password for `find*` methods. Replace 
 `password: req.body.password` with `password: hash_password(req.body.password)`. (Assuming hash_password method works this way)

Comment: Yeah, I was just changing my code to something similar. It's unfortunately that there's no lifecycle on `find` :(

Comment: Yes. There is a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28167738/1435132